# AngularJS Prevent $watch from firing when syncing data model with URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to keep a data model in sync with the url:

When my url updates, and `$stateParams` changes, `selectedNode` is found

```
$scope.$watch('$stateParams', function (params) {
  // some logic
  $scope.selectedNode = foundNode
});
```

When selectedNode changes, the url updates

```
$scope.$watch('selectedNode', function(node) {
  // some logic to find params
  $state.go('nodeState', params);
});
```

Only problem is, when `$stateParams` changes, selectedNode changed, which fires the $watcher, thus changing `$stateParams` again,

And the same is true for when `selectedNode` changes (causes `$stateParams` to change, causing selectedNode to change thus again)

The end goal seems pretty simple, to keep my data model `selectedNode` in sync with the url (both ways).

Comment: Can't you remove the watch once it is loaded?

Comment: Once what is loaded? The controller? If $stateParams changes after the controller loads, then removing this watch isn't a good idea. I always want to watch selectedNode because this changes, say when the user clicks on something

Comment: Unless I am not understanding how/when to remove the watch! :/

Comment: aah.. All your states are managed by the same controller? Where do these code reside?

Comment: Is it feasible to watch specific properties instead of the whole objects? If not, does setting $watch's third parameter `objectEquality` to `true` (although could be slow if comparing large objects).

Comment: This could potentially be a design issue and watches have been used to get over that? If you are using ui router, instead of watching for stateparams you could listen to the statechanged events..., have a service to abstract out the logic for generating params and url for the target? Possibly i am wrong.. dont have a complete picture of what you have..

Comment: Listening for events would cause the same loop, as selectedNode is set from the stateParams

Comment: Why are you watching selectedNode?

Comment: I'm watching selectedNode because when the user clicks on an element, it changes selectedNode

Comment: @TaylorMac Then you should just do it in the `ng-click` right? Why to add a watch for that?

Comment: @TalorMac: This clearly a design issue. You have one thing that when changed changes another thing which in turn changes the first thing again. There might be work-arounds (e.g. temporarily disabling one of the `$watches`, but there is clearly a better option available).